# Is there a way to change RStudio's (Posit) 'Graph' panel size programatically?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm curious to know if there's a way to resize the panels in RStudio's IDE, especially the plot (graph) panel. Or at least extract the current size of the panel so I can reuse it in my script.

I'm not looking for the `png()` or `pdf()` functions. Is using the mouse the only way to resize the panels in RStudio?

[image]

Comment: I think `dev.size()` gives you the current size of the plot panel.

Comment: I don't think there's a documented function to make changes.  It would be in the `rstudioapi` package if there was, and I can't spot anything there.  There may be some way to simulate the mouse actions; the RStudio display is done using an HTML browser.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the size of the panel itself? If you choose the "Export" option, it allows you to specify width and height in pixels and you can preview the image with those dimensions. You can also maximize the size of panels in RStudio with the View menu.

Comment: To be clear, I want to resize the 'Plots' panel programatically, i.e., I want to write code that will make sure to resize the plot panel with a width of at least X and a height of at least Y.